# PHP keeps adding a new line of a product to cart if already exists

Tags: php, arrays, session

I just wondered if anyone could tell me the reason why this code is not working?

```
if($cart_count == 0)
{

    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $tmp_product;

} else if($cart_count > 0) {

    // if the array has anything in it:

    for($i=0; $i<$cart_count; $i++)
    { 
        // loop through the array rows:

        // if the id of the product already is in there then add to it:
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$i]['id'] === $tmp_product['id'])
        {
            // adds to the already there qty: preincrement actually I think
            $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'] += $tmp_product['qty'];                

        } else {

            // otherwise add to it regardless of the conditional kind of...
            $_SESSION['cart'][] = $tmp_product;

        }
    }
}
```

I mean I thought I was being correct with my logic is there any reason why when I go to add the first product to the cart and then I go and add more to it, that works fine.

Though when I go to another unique product than the first added row, why every time I go and add that it keeps adding extra rows to the session? It's truly bizarre and I just can't seem to get my head around it, sure it's something I am just not seeing.

To understand this better I have outputted an example of what it should not be doing:

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Product Test 1
            [price] => 12.55
            [qty] => 1
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Product 2
            [price] => 52.22
            [qty] => 9
        )

        [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Product 2
            [price] => 52.22
            [qty] => 6
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Try using `==` instead of `===`, maybe it's a type issue.

Comment: Are you sure the $tmp_product['id'] is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Yes it is, I have just checked the datatype even of the id's and they are identical. I did try just as == rather than === but same result apppears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, strange. I don't know if i'm on the right track, but i did some changes to your code.

- I removed `if($cart_count > 0)`. If the logic for removing items from the cart is correct, then $cart_count can never go below zero. And, if one case is comparing $cart_count with 0, then there is only one case left for the else, which allows to skip a above zero comparison.
- Inside the for statement: every time an item is not found (as already being in the card) a new item is inserted. you can see how often this gets called by adding a `echo 'adding product';` to your code.
- i've changed this to insert product, if already there, then break out of the for loop. and added a flag $product_already_there.

Maybe you can play around with that and see if it works out.

---

```
if($cart_count === 0) {                 // no items in the cart
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $tmp_product; // add first item
} else {
    // there are already items in the cart array

    $product_already_there = false;

    // if product is already in the cart, increase product quantity
    for($i = 0; $i < $cart_count; $i++)
    {     
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$i]['id'] === $tmp_product['id']) {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'] = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'] + $tmp_product['qty'];
            $product_already_there = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // else add a new product to the cart
    if($product_already_there === false) {
         $_SESSION['cart'][] = $tmp_product;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will definitely give that a go and play around with it, looks somewhat more direct (I think is the expression I would use).

I will also get back to you when I have modified my own.

Comment: Playing with source codes always fun and it works, I literally can't thank you enough.